# r- ggplot2 color and fills not functioning

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to visualize a single scatterplot using ggplot2 and adjust the colors to make the graph more visually appealing, however, the `colors` and `fill` functions are not populating the colors I want.

For reference I've looked through [this very helpful link](http://r-statistics.co/ggplot2-Tutorial-With-R.html) in addition to the [`tidyverse` cheatsheets for ggplot2](https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/blob/master/data-visualization-2.1.pdf), neither of which cover how to change the color of one single variable.

See below dummy data set with chart example below showing desired colors as the variable names:

```
dfRaw<- as.data.frame(cbind(var1= rnorm(10,11,3), var2= rnorm(10,12,2)))

rawPlot<- ggplot(dfRaw, aes(x= var1, y= var2, fill= 'skyblue', color= 'skyblue')) + geom_point()
> rawPlot
```

[image: scatterplot showing var1 vs. var2 with wrong colors]

In the above, `skyblue` is being desginated as the `fill` and `color` but is neither. This happens whether I use one or both designations. I'm looking for advice on how to fix this in addition to directions to a *color list* for `ggplot2`.

Comment: `fill` in combination with `geom_point` only makes a difference if `shape` is a number between `21` and `25`. Take a look at `ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 1:25, y = 1:25)) + geom_point(aes(x, y, shape = y), fill = "skyblue", size = 2) + scale_shape_identity()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `aes` defines *variables* that map to different `colour`s and `fill`s and not colours and fills directly. Supplying the colour directly in `geom_point` (or outside `aes`) works:

```
rawPlot <- ggplot(dfRaw, aes(x=var1, y=var2)) +
   geom_point(colour='skyblue', fill='skyblue')
rawPlot
```

[image]